# How to create at test user account for inapp purchase?

Tags: iphone, in-app-purchase

Can anyone explain me in detail or send me some link that will explain How to create test user account for inapp purchase?

Comment: You can go through this link : [In App Purchase](http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/iphone/iphone-sdk-in-app-purchases/) For further details, this may help you: [Provisioning Profile](http://www.wikihow.com/Create-a-Provisioning-Profile-for-iPhone)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Can you see this in your iTunes Connect page?
[image]

If not, make sure you have information in these two sections ready:
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1):

You need to login into your itunesconnect account. then choose Members menu (in the bottom left) add a test account.

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/LanguagesUtilities/Conceptual/iTunesConnect_Guide/Chapters/SettingUpUserAccounts.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011225-CH25-SW10