# iPhone application with in-app purchase upload

Tags: iphone, upload, in-app-purchase

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to create at test user account for inapp purchase?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4710773/how-to-create-at-test-user-account-for-inapp-purchase)

I am uploading my iPhone application having In-App purchase implemented in it. Should I give any test accounts in Review notes for in-app purchase testing.
Please help me.

Answer (score 0):

Think about it.. Apple aren't going to reject your app because you unnecessarily included your test account details in the Review Notes. They may, however, reject it if you don't.

Answer (score 0):

you need to provide the IAP test user accounts in "Notes" section so that apple reviewers can simulate the IAP for you application.